# Continue handling receipts after log in

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I implemented auto renew subscriptions in my app. By default app tries to use production URL for handling receipts, if code returns 27001, app will use sandbox URL. So if I run app from XCode and sandbox account is specified in the iPhone Setting (iTunes/AppStore), app tries at second attempt to load product details for sandbox and does it successfully. Because product array is not empty, I am able to buy a subscription after confirmation prompt. It looks like code working as expected but not in all conditions.

App Review Team does the following: they log off from real and sandbox account in the device settings. In this case if they run app, app shows prompt to log in, because in the ViewController app checks for status of subscriptions. They press Cancel. Next they go to BuySubscriptionViewController and press Cancel again. So at this moment product array is empty and it is not possible to buy a product.

I added the following condition:

```
@IBAction func buySub(_ sender: Any) {

        if (product_mysub != nil) {
            StoreManager.shared.buy(product: product_mysub)
        } else {
            requestData()
        }
    }
```

So if a product wasn't found I am asking user to log in again if he tries to buy it.

```
func requestData() {
        let receiptManager: ReceiptManager = ReceiptManager()
        receiptManager.startValidatingReceipts()
    }
```

from ReceiptManager.swift:

```
func startValidatingReceipts() {
        do {
            _ = try self.getReceiptURL()?.checkResourceIsReachable()
            do {
                let receiptData = try Data(contentsOf: self.getReceiptURL()!)
                self.validateData(data: receiptData)
                print("Receipt exists")
            } catch {
                print("Not able to get data from URL")
            }
        } catch {
            guard UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "didRefreshReceipt") == false else {
                print("Stopping after second attempt")
                return
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "didRefreshReceipt")
            let receiptRequest = SKReceiptRefreshRequest()
            receiptRequest.delegate = self
            receiptRequest.start()
            print("Receipt URL Doesn't exist", error.localizedDescription)

        }
    }
```

If users taps on a button again, app doesn't ask him to log in again and gets data about products. If user taps third time on the button, app shows confirmation prompt to buy a product. How can I continue purchase flow after entering email and password without asking user to press the button 2 times yet?

```
    extension ReceiptManager: SKRequestDelegate {
        func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) {
// this func is not executed after entering account details in the prompt and pressing OK


        }

        func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            print("Error refreshing receipt", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you fail to retrieve the receipt once, don't try again.  Simply let the user use the purchase button or the restore button (you do have one of those right?).  If they try and purchase a subscription they already have then iOS will tell them that and the transaction will be processed st zero cost. Either way, the use understands the login request as a result of the purchase/restore. If they still cancel that login request then they are left without an active subscription, but they have a further opportunity to purchase/restore. The unexpected login requests are bad UX